# Can someone explain to me why "this" is not equal to win or window in the following javascript IIFE code?

Tags: javascript

When executing this code below, results are false, why? What is "this" bound to? I was expecting the results to be true in both alert statements

```
(function(win){

     alert("this == win: "+ this == win);         // false
     alert("this == window: "+ this == window);   // false

})(window);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: WRONG DUPES, has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Inside function this indicates function. Which in your case is anonymous function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is nothing to do with this not equal window, it is an order of operation issue....

what the parser sees is this:

```
("this == win: "+ this) == win
```

Add in the correct parenthesis

```js
(function(win){

     console.log("this == win: "+ (this == win));        
     console.log("this == window: "+ (this == window));   

})(window);
```

Comment: Isnt 'this' inside function should be function itself?

Comment: No, it is based on the context of how it is called. You need to read the links that were posted as dupes.

Comment: this upgrade my knowledge a lot